# Eliminar Objeto de arraylist en LIBGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

```
private List<LadrilloVERDEEntity> LadrilloVERDElist = new  ArrayList<LadrilloVERDEEntity>();
LadrilloVERDElist.add(new LadrilloVERDEEntity(world, ladriVerdeTexture,10,3));
LadrilloVERDElist.remove(1);// Acá es donde me marca error
```

Me gustaría eliminar el primer objeto creado.

Comment: prueba con LadrilloVERDElist.remove(0); si solo tienes un elemento en tu ArrayList este posee el index 0 y no el 1.

Comment: @Bourne , si tenias razón gracias

Answer (score 1):

Ten presente algunas cosas:

1.- En java el primer índice de una lista (o arreglo) es el cero:

```
private List LadrilloVERDElist = new  ArrayList();
LadrilloVERDElist.add(new LadrilloVERDEEntity(world, ladriVerdeTexture,10,3));
LadrilloVERDElist.remove(0);// el primer índice es el cero no el uno
```

2.- En libgdx es mejor usar las clases propias de la librería (para que puedas portar el juego), te recomiendo en vez de usar la clase List uses la clase Array disponible en el paquete com.badlogic.gdx.utils